# How to fast alter table when a system isolates tenants' data by database?

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi-tenany system. My senior staff suggest to isolate tenants' data by database, not by schema nor discriminator.

My question is, if I have 1000 customers, therefore I have 1000 databases also.
So, now because of a new feature, I need to alter tables for the 1000 databases. Is if possible? Or, is there a easy way to alter tables for the 1000 databases ?

The hardware of my PostgreSQL is 32 core/256GB RAM, how many databases can an instance of PostgreSQL handle ?

Comment: Do it in a bash loop of all customer tables?

Comment: Or multiple, simultaneous bash loops, if the list of databases is generated using a window function.

Comment: Maybe even Gnu Parallels.

Comment: um... I know. I just wonder whethere there are better ways.

Comment: Application code is best for something like this. In a past job we managed ~1,000 customer databases, and we built our own tool to iterate every customer database or specific groups of them (depending on our goal) to deploy database changes or run SQL scripts. And no, there's not much better ways than writing your own process or tool.

Comment: No, there is no better way. Perhaps your senior staff was misguided.

Comment: @wureka you didn't mention ways that you knew to do, and that you were already trying.  Thus, we could not know what you already know.